# Grails GORM Inheritance best practices

Tags: grails, inheritance, grails-orm

I am working on a grails project with potentially 36 domain classes each with a dozen plus unique properties and a handful of shared properties that can be inherited from a base domain class.   The problem with this is that grails will generate 1 table with all the properties from all the domain classes that inherit from the base class.   This means a table with well over 300 columns which seems problematic on multiple levels.  The other route is to do away with inheritance and each domain represents a unique database table.  No matter what, either a lot of time will be spent duplicating code or trying to manage the generated database.  Is there another option that I am missing?

All thoughts and opinions welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear you are missing the all important `tablePerHierarchy` mapping value for domain classes. I highly recommend you read the [Inheritance Strategies](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/guide/GORM.html#inheritanceStrategies) documentation regarding this.

From the documentation:

> By default GORM classes use table-per-hierarchy inheritance mapping.
>   This has the disadvantage that columns cannot have a NOT-NULL
>   constraint applied to them at the database level. If you would prefer
>   to use a table-per-subclass inheritance strategy you can do so as
>   follows:

```
class Payment {
    Integer amount
    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
}

class CreditCardPayment extends Payment {
    String cardNumber
}
```

> The mapping of the root Payment class specifies that it will not be
>   using table-per-hierarchy mapping for all child classes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inheritance between classes. It is very hard to make refactors in classes with inheritance.

You can use dynamic behavior for common classes through interfaces, or maybe re-think the design in the model classes.